# what directory should I put this script in

Tags: php, mysql

I use a hosting server. I would like to simply open some text files with PHP and write some of the data into my server's database.
      This is unrelated to any front-end/user activity.
   I have never done this before and I am not sure where is the optimal location on the server...
I see directories at top level such as PHP is that it?

I should also add that I do not understand how to execute a PHP script in a non-HTML form context

please advise on that as well
  sorry if this is stupid.

Comment: is there a way to execute a script via cPanel??

Comment: ok, if cron is the only answer then this is obviously a duplicate question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what directory should I put this script in?
>    I would like to simply open some text files with PHP and write some of the data into my local database

I usually have a `bin` directory in my project directory (next to `webroot`).

> I see directories at top level such as PHP is that it?

I can't see any reason to have a top level PHP directory in the first place.

> I should also add that I do not understand how to execute a PHP script in a non-HTML form context

Assuming it has a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line, you just run it:

```
~/projects/myProject/bin/myScript.php
```

or (and not needing the shebang):

```
php ~/projects/myProjects/bin/myScript.php
```

Comment: i do everything through cpanel, i don't know how to access a commond line with the shebang

Comment: there already is a bin directory next to web-root, i could work there

Comment: are you saying to run the php script locally from my machine? does it matter that it is not running on my web server... thinking about it seems like only the database connection is what matters since i am not worried about any html stuff

Comment: No, I wasn't suggesting running it from your own machine. SSH is the standard means to access a command line on a remote machine.

Comment: oh ok thanks, only thing is i'm not sure how to ssh into my server ( i pay for it)... i've got to believe there is an easier way to execute the php script

Comment: Typing `php` followed by the path to the script is *not* hard!

Comment: "inmotionhosting does not offer ssh access..."

Comment: Wow. I'll make a note to never go near them then.

Comment: no, you are right, of course they have SSH, i just hadn't seen the part of cPanel where you can login with a java applet... I think I'm all set now... i will accept your anser